# Can I use 'ifwinexist' as an argument in a function?

Tags: autohotkey

Please have a look at the code below

```
;----------------------------------------------------------------
;  INFORMATION
;----------------------------------------------------------------
; Full resolution is 2560 * 1600
; 
; Taskbar is 40 pixels high
;----------------------------------------------------------------
#NoEnv
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

^j::ResizeWin()

ResizeWin()
{
  ifwinexist ahk_exe Chrome.exe                     ;Google Chrome
  DoTheThing(0,0,1280,800)

  ifwinexist ahk_class CommunicatorMainWindowClass  ;Skype
  DoTheThing(0,800,400,760)

  ifwinexist ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32               ;Outlook
  DoTheThing(1280,0,1280,1560)

  ifwinexist ahk_exe WhatsApp.exe                   ;WhattsApp
  DoTheThing(400,800,880,760)
}

DoTheThing(posX = 0, posY = 0, Width = 0, Height = 0)
{
  WinActivate
  WinMove,%WindowID%,,posX,posY,%Width%,%Height%
}
```

I wrote the code above to rearrange my opened windows on my desktop whenever i dragged them somewhere different. This works fine at the moment, but I think there is a possibility to clean up the code by handling the picking of the windows within the call of the function.

In my mind I should end up with just multiple instances of

```
DoTheThing(posX,posY,Width,Height,Name/class/exe_of_the_window)
```

And handle activation and moving in the function main body.
How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest solution, I think:

```
^j::ResizeWin()

ResizeWin(){
  WinMove, ahk_exe Chrome.exe,, 0,0,1280,800
  WinMove, ahk_class CommunicatorMainWindowClass,, 0,800,400,760
  ; ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, the example I had was so over engineered. Thanks, this solves it.

Comment: Just to let you know, If a window is minimized, it will not work. Then I have to include WinAcitvate ahk_class ... for it to work.